# How to upload multiple WAR files to Tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat, war

We been using Tomcat to host our Java Web Services that our PHP website will call.

We have have few environments, meaning we have a few Tomcat Servers. Each time we change a Web Service we have to upload the WAR file to all the Servers.  And it becomes a lot of work, for each server uploading one war file at a time.

Is there a way to upload multiple WAR files to Tomcat? And maybe later on I can write a program to do the uploading for us.

Any advice or links that can help, point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

---

#### Update

So I did a little more googling and found out that Tomcat allows you to send single request URI. A given example is:
`http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/foo`

For some reason its not working with me, keeps telling me access denied. Will keep trying

Comment: you need to upload multiple war files to tomcat OR upload one war to multiple tomcats?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy the first part, upload multiple war files to Tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just copy the WAR files to the `\webapps` directory in Tomcat.

- Windows: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps`
- Linux: `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`

Tomcat will deploy the WAR files automatically.  If it does not deploy automatically, then try  restarting Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Search the net for this I came across [Tcat](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat-leading-enterprise-apache-tomcat-application-server) that has this functionality:

> Deploy multiple applications across servers. Rollback bad deployments
>
> ```
> 1.View complete deployment history
> 2.Rollback to earlier versions
> 3.Deploy, undeploy and redeploy multiple applications
> ```

Of course this is a paid software...

Comment: It is a good solution but I am not prepared to pay for software at this point.